# Strict Standards: Non-static method, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php

I have that and "Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method" after updating to php 5.5.

I know the fix is to kinda change "::" to "->" somewhere in the following php but I am unsure how to format it..

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $before_widget;
            if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            wp_custom_sidebar_plugin::query_custom_sidebar();
            echo $after_widget;
        }
```

It's the second to last line I need to fix...just not sure how to write this php.

Heres the full code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WordPress Custom Sidebar
Plugin URI: http://www.typomedia.org/wordpress/plugins/wordpress-custom-sidebar/
Description: With this plugin you can handle sidebar contents like posts and assign them from a dropdown menu.
Author: Typomedia Foundation
Version: 2.3
Author URI: http://www.typomedia.org/
*/

if ( !class_exists ('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin')) {
    class wp_custom_sidebar_plugin {

    function custom_sidebar_textdomain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'wpcsp', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
    }

    function custom_sidebar_addcolumn() {
        global $wpdb;
        if (false === $wpdb->query("SELECT post_sidebar FROM $wpdb->posts LIMIT 0")) {
            $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $wpdb->posts ADD COLUMN post_sidebar varchar(200)");
        }
    }

    function custom_sidebar_insert_post($pID) {
        global $wpdb;
        extract($_POST);
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_sidebar = '$post_sidebar' WHERE ID = $pID");
    }

    function custom_sidebar_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Sidebars', 'wpcsp'),
            'singular_name' => __('Sidebar', 'wpcsp'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'wpcsp'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Sidebar', 'wpcsp'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Sidebar', 'wpcsp'),
            'new_item' => __('New Sidebar', 'wpcsp'),
            'all_items' => __('All Sidebars', 'wpcsp'),
            'view_item' => __('View Sidebars', 'wpcsp'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Sidebars', 'wpcsp'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No Sidebars found', 'wpcsp'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Sidebars found in Trash', 'wpcsp'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' =>  __('Sidebars', 'wpcsp')
            );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'public' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions' ),
        );

        register_post_type('sidebar',$args);
    }

    function custom_sidebar_dropdown_box($post) {
        global $post;
        $post_sidebar = $post->post_sidebar;
            $sidebars = wp_dropdown_pages(array(
            'post_type' => 'sidebar',
            'selected' => $post->post_sidebar, 
            'name' => 'post_sidebar',
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_date',
            ));
            ?>
            <p><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=sidebar"><?php _e('Create new sidebar', 'wpcsp') ?></a></p>
            <?php
    }

    function custom_sidebar_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box('custom_sidebar', __('Sidebar', 'wpscp'), array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_dropdown_box'), 'post', 'side', 'low');
        add_meta_box('custom_sidebar', __('Sidebar', 'wpscp'), array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_dropdown_box'), 'page', 'side', 'low');
    }

    function query_custom_sidebar() {
            global $post;
            $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);

            if ( is_single() || is_page() && $post->post_sidebar ) {
                $sidebar_id = $post->post_sidebar;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'sidebar',
                    'p' => $sidebar_id
                    );
            }

            elseif ( is_single() || is_page() && $parent->post_sidebar ) {          
                $sidebar_id = $parent->post_sidebar;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'sidebar',
                    'p' => $sidebar_id
                    );
            }

            else {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'sidebar',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'order' => 'ASC',           
                );
            }       

            // The Loop
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                the_content();
            endwhile;
            // Reset Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    function custom_sidebar_register_widget() {
        register_widget( 'custom_sidebar_widget' );
    }

    function custom_sidebar_default_entry() {
        global $wpdb;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'sidebar',
            'post_title' => 'Default Sidebar',
            'post_content' => '<h2>WordPress Custom Sidebar 2.1</h2>This plugin is a development of <a title="Designstudio, Philipp Speck" href="http://www.destio.de" target="_blank">Designstudio, Philipp Speck &raquo;</a>',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
            );  

        $columns = get_posts('post_type=sidebar');
        // check if not exsist then insert default entry
        if (empty($columns)) {
                wp_insert_post($args);
        }
    } // end function custom_sidebar_default_entry

    function plugin_header() {
        global $post_type;
        ?>
    <style>
    <?php if (($_GET['post_type'] == 'sidebar') || ($post_type == 'sidebar')) : ?>
        #icon-edit { background:transparent url('<?php echo plugins_url( 'icon32.png', __FILE__ );?>') no-repeat -4px -5px; }
    <?php endif; ?>
        #adminmenu #menu-posts-sidebar div.wp-menu-image{background:transparent url('<?php echo plugins_url( 'icon16.png', __FILE__ );?>') no-repeat scroll 1px -33px;}
        #adminmenu #menu-posts-sidebar:hover div.wp-menu-image,#adminmenu #menu-posts-sidebar.wp-has-current-submenu div.wp-menu-image{background:transparent url('<?php echo plugins_url( 'icon16.png', __FILE__ );?>') no-repeat scroll 1px -1px;}
    </style>
    <?php
    }   

    } // end class wp_custom_sidebar_plugin
} // end class_exists check

if ( !class_exists ('custom_sidebar_widget')) {
    class custom_sidebar_widget extends WP_Widget {

        function custom_sidebar_widget() {
            $options = array( 'description' => __('To assign custom sidebars inside post or pages drag the widget to an area of your choice.', 'wpcsp') );
            parent::WP_Widget( false, __('Custom Sidebar', 'wpcsp'), $options );
        }

        function widget( $args, $instance ) {           
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $before_widget;
            if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            wp_custom_sidebar_plugin::query_custom_sidebar();
            echo $after_widget;
        }

    } // close custom_sidebar_widget class
} // end class_exists check

add_action('init', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_textdomain'));
add_action('init', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_addcolumn'));
add_action('init', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_post_type'));
add_action('plugins_loaded', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_default_entry'));
add_action('widgets_init', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_register_widget'));
add_action('admin_menu', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_meta_box'));
add_action('wp_insert_post', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin','custom_sidebar_insert_post'));
add_action('admin_head', array('wp_custom_sidebar_plugin', 'plugin_header'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try to change

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
```

to

```
public static function widget( $args, $instance ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `query_custom_sidebar` in static context when it is not a static method.  Try either making the `query_custom_sidebar` a static function or create an instance of the `wp_custom_sidebar_plugin` class and call the method `query_custom_sidebar` through that instance.